# no me muestra el codigo php

Tags: php

buen dia a todos, he estado buscando por todos lados y no me queda, tengo xampp en windows 10 y estoy empezando con php, el problema es que al momento de ejecutar codigo php no me genera el resultado, me genera el codigo tal cual escrito en mi editor de texto, ejemplo con el HOLA MUNDO
así tal cual me genera el resultado, que es lo que puede ser?

```
<?php
echo 'hola mundo';
?>
```

Comment: Tienes q entrar desde el servidor xamp. Tú estás entrando al fichero de esta forma : c:\.... Debes entrar desde localhost para acceder mediante tu xamp y así ejecutará el código como PHP y no como texto plano

Comment: Documentación oficial de Xampp: [¿Dónde debo colocar mi contenido web?](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/faq_windows.html)

Comment: Hola, lo mas probable es que lo hayas integrado en un archivo `.html` o con otra extensión, si es así prueba poniendo la extensión `.php`

Answer (score 0):

Estas accediendo desde tu localhost? O directamente desde la URL en el navegador?

Tienes que poner en el navegador la ruta de tu localhost/ubicacionfichero

Answer (score 0):

esto pasa por entrar sin el localhost, estas entrando poniendo la ruta donde esta el archivo tal cual "C:/script_php/index.php" eso da el error deberias hacer lo siguiente para solucionarlo:
1- Abre el xampp y dale ala opcion de la derecha explorer
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2-Esto te abrira los directorios de xampp ahora deberas darle a la carpeta htdocs
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3- Ahi soltaras tu carpeta con tu script de php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4- iniciaras el apache y mysql del xampp
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5- ahora deberas acceder al navegador
http://localhost/proyecto_php/

y ya ejecutara bien el archivo php